# PPM scanning and printing

Tags: c, file, printf, scanf

I want to scan in documents from a file of type .ppm which are image files but follows the following data structure

```
P3
4 4
255
255 255   0 255 255   0 255 255   0 255 255   0 
255 255   0 255   0   0 128 128 128 255 255   0 
255 255   0   0 255   0   0   0 255 255 255   0 
255 255   0 255 255   0 255 255   0 255 255   0
```

Every 3 integers mark a column so after the first 3 lines, this marks a pattern of a 4x4 table as indicated on the second line.

My first step is to read in a file like this where the height and width can vary and then reprint it in the exact format using scanf and printf.

My attempt at this is as follows:

```
scanf(" %d%d %d", &width, &height, &depth);
printf("P3\n%d %d\n %d\n", width, height, depth);

   while(scanf("%c", &input) >= 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            printf("%c %c %c ", input, input, input);
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: the inner loop prints linefeed many times. Strange.

Comment: Going to the first line of code. The first space before `%d` does not skip the `"P3"` text. The second space is irrelevant since most format specifiers including `%d` skip whitespace such as newline anyway (a common trap: not `%c`). But I am mystified why you subsequently use `%c` when integer data is supplied. When the input is `"255"` format `%c` will read `'2'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of errors in your code:

1. You only scan `input` once. Therefore all of your pixels will have the same value. You probably want to call `scanf` in the inner loop.
2. The format specifier `%c` only reads in one character and not a number. You should use `%d` even though the range of your pixel values fits within a byte.
3. As already mentioned, the inner loop prints nothing but linefeeds. This belongs into the outer loop.
4. The `print` should be called in the inner loop but with different arguments unless you want to write black and white images only: `printf("%d %d %d ", r, g, b);`. Again you need to use `%d` instead of `%c`.
5. As mentioned in another comment, you need to skip the "P3" in the header. You could modify your first line to `scanf("%*s %d %d %d", &width, &height, &depth);`. The '%*s' reads a string without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @compute: No, as far as I can see your question has not been updated.